# How do I turn oddly shaped arrays into a tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a bunch of numpy arrays with different shapes and dimensions, and I need to turn it all into one tensorflow tensor as input to a neural network.

I'm trying to use this network on a reinforcement learning problem, and at each time step it needs a single tensor. I have six numpy arrays, here are their shapes: (26,) (7,) (2,) (7,) (2,) (9,7). I've put them all into one array of shape (6,), but when I try to create a tf.constant with them, I run into problems.

```py
#here are the numpy arrays

in1_ = np.zeros((26,), dtype='int')
in2_ = np.zeros((7,), dtype='int')
in3_ = np.zeros((2,), dtype='int')
in4_ = np.zeros((7,), dtype='int')
in5_ = np.zeros((2,), dtype='int')
in6_ = np.zeros((9,7), dtype='int')

#in practice the arrays would contain data, not just zeros

final_array = np.array([in1_, in2_, in3_, in4_, in5_, in6_])
final_array.shape
>>>(6,)
#so I can create the big array, but I get an error when creating 
#a tf.constant

const = tf.constant(final_array)
>>>TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I know that both tensors and numpy arrays have to be rectangular, so I thought that converting an array to a tensor would be simple. I can actually make it work if i use strings instead of arrays, but for my purposes it would be better not to do that.

Comment: Look at that `final_array` in more detail.  It is 1d (6,) shape, but it is also object dtype.  It's little better than the list you gave it:  `[int1_, int2_,...]`.  You need a deeper understanding of what a tensor is like - possible shapes and contents.  `rectangular` numpy arrays can only be composed from arrays with the same shape, e.g. `np.array(np.ones(7), np.zeros(7), np.arange(7)]`.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah I can see that using a numpy array doesn't add much, but even when I just use a list I get a TypeError. I don't see a way to make either the np array or the list rectangular without messing with the data inside. Or do tensors not have to be rectangular?

Comment: Don't you think it would be easier to train (and test) a net using a set of images all the same size, say  32x32, than a mix of image sizes (some 64x53, others 4x4, etc).  Have you read some of the theory behind the code?  or are you just winging it after reading a turtorial or two?  Maybe some of the tensorflow docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an array containing integers you have created an array containing other arrays (note that `final_array.dtype` is not `dtype('int64')`). This is possible for numpy arrays, but not possible for tensorflow arrays (a tensorflow array can't contain other tensorflow arrays). This is why you get an error when you try to convert it.

There is no way around this, tensorflow will not allow to have not matching dimension sizes. But since you want to use those arrays as an input to your network you can combine them into one array first and convert them afterwards:

```
final_array = np.concatenate((in1_, in2_, in3_, in4_, in5_, in6_.reshape(-1)))
const = tf.constant(final_array)
```

Comment: Is it okay for final_array to be just a block of integers? I'm new to neural nets, but my understanding was that it's better for a network to have it's input split up into vectors. That way it can seperate one input from another.

Comment: @ytubien Do you want to use all the vectors in a single forward pass or multiple forward passes?

Comment: All the vectors will go through in one forward pass, then at the next time step there will be a different set of vectors, but of the same shape.

Comment: @ytubien then you have to concatenate them. Since you have vectors as input you will use fully connected layers, and those can only get a batch of arrays as input. Each forward pass will be one array out of the batch. So the data has to be one dimensional.

Comment: @ytubien also convert them to floats and try to normalize your input vectors to be somewhere in range of -1 to 1 if possible.